# Sort an array for an objects double property

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I need to reorder an NSMutableArray using a property of the objects inside of it.

I did this for dates in a previous project with dates but this method won't accept doubles:

```
NSUInteger rowIndex = [self.alist indexOfObject:assignment inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.alist.count) options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:^(AssignmentInfo *obj1, AssignmentInfo *obj2) {

    NSDate *date1 = obj1.dateTime;
    NSDate *date2 = obj2.dateTime;

    if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

So no I need a way to reorder the array `self.communitiesArray` for the double value of the community object inside the array. `self.community.distanceFromUser` which is the double.

Using some of the answers below I am getting an error on:

```
NSUInteger rowIndex = [self.communitiesArray indexOfObject:community inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.communitiesArray.count) options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:^(Community *obj1, Community *obj2) {
```

Error says : Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(Community *_*strong, Community **_strong)' to parameter of type 'NSComparator' (aka 'NSComparisonResult (^)(__strong id, __strong id)')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort your array.

```
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"community.distanceFromUser" ascending:YES]]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `double`s are primitives, you do not need to use the `compare:` method on them: comparing them with the regular operators should be sufficient. Your comparator block would look as follows:

```
double d1 = obj1.doubleValue;
double d2 = obj2.doubleValue;
if (d1 < d2) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}
if (d1 > d2) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}
return NSOrderedSame;
```

An even better approach would be using `NSSortdescriptor`s: they let you sort your objects based on the properties they expose without writing any additional code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dblDescr= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"doubleValue" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [myData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dblDescr]];
```

Comment: I am getting an error on:  `NSUInteger rowIndex = [self.communitiesArray indexOfObject:community inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.communitiesArray.count) options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:^(Community *obj1, Community *obj2) {`

Error says : Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(Community *__strong, Community *__strong)' to parameter of type 'NSComparator' (aka 'NSComparisonResult (^)(__strong id, __strong id)')

Comment: @SteveEdwin Change the type of `obj1` and `obj2` to `id obj1, id obj2` in the declaration, and either add a cast to `Community*`, or use square bracket syntax `double d1=[obj1 doubleValue]` instead of dot syntax `double d1 = obj1.doubleValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the `double`s directly, i.e., in the comparator:

```
double a = obj1.distanceFromUser;
double b = obj2.distanceFromUser;
if (a < b) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
} else if (a > b) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
} else {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on:  `NSUInteger rowIndex = [self.communitiesArray indexOfObject:community inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.communitiesArray.count) options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:^(Community *obj1, Community *obj2) {`

Error says : Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(Community *__strong, Community *__strong)' to parameter of type 'NSComparator' (aka 'NSComparisonResult (^)(__strong id, __strong id)')

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `double` is a primitive type so you can use the comparison operators to compare them

```
NSUInteger rowIndex =
     [self.communitiesArray indexOfObject:community
                            inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.communitiesArray.count)
                                  options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                          usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult (Community *obj1, Community *obj2) {
       double distance1 = obj1.distanceFromUser;
       double distance2 = obj2.distanceFromUser;
       if (distance1 < distance2)
           return NSOrderedAscending;
       if (distance1 < distance2)
           return NSOrderedDescending;
       return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Notice the block signature: you were passing `^(Community *obj1, Community *obj2)`, which is interpreted as `^void (Community *obj1, Community *obj2)`, whereas you have to include the correct return type, i.e. `^NSComparisonResult (Community *obj1, Community *obj2)`

Comment: It doesn't actually sort? I see the values getting filled up but nothing happens?